# Where is the file that is saved by model.save() command

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was using TensorFlow to train a machine learning model.
I use the command `model.save('my_model.h5')` to save my model .
Where is the exact location path that the model file is saved?
Will it simply overwrite the old one if I run the code again?
Many thanks.

Comment: Have you run that command and then looked for the file? - I assume that it's saving into whatever the current directory is.  You can supply an absolute path, in which case you can decide exactly to where the model is saved.

Comment: I don't know where to look for it. Yes, I did run the command, multiple times.

Comment: How to supply it ?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: windows 10, using visual studio to write code.

Comment: If you run `import os; print(os.getcwd())`, that will print the current working directory.  That should be where the model is being saved.

Comment: I don't know windows, but you should be able to save to your home directory with something like `r'C:\Users\<YourUserName>\my_model.h5'`.

Comment: Yes, I found the path and the file, thank you. It is in users\user folder

Comment: Yay!  Maybe we should make a real answer then?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `model.save()` is just a standard OS path.  Since you're giving it a relative path, it is saving the model in whatever the current working directory is.  To know what that is, run the following:

```
import os;
print(os.getcwd())
```

just before your call to save the model.  If you want, you can supply a full path in the call to `model.save()`, in which case it will save the model to that location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Model will saved in the current directory and the model will overwrite the oldone when saving the same model with same name.if you need various model just change the name of the model while saving the model each time.

Answer (score -1):

The 'my_model.h5' file will be saved to your working directory. To check your current working directory, execute the following line in your python IDE:

```
pwd
```

This will return the path of where the file was saved. If you want to specify a different path, simply add it before the filename in your save command. e.g.

```
model.save('/Users/yourname/my/desired/path/my_model.h5')
```

Yes, by default model.save() will overwrite the original. Here are the default parameters according to [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model)

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, save_format=None,
    signatures=None, options=None, save_traces=True)
```

Comment: I see, so instead of the only file name, you put the whole path in the command, thank you very much !!!